# Using gulp for insert html in js

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have two files, js

```
(function (Controllers) {
    var DialogElement = (function () {
        function DialogElement() {
            this._template = "include:'Views/Dialog.html'";
        }
        return DialogElement;
    }());
    Controllers.DialogElement = DialogElement;
})(Controllers));
```

and html

```
<div>Simple dialog!</div>
```

I want used **gulp** replaces variable `this._template = "include:'Views/Dialog.html'";` on the contents of the html file.

To get so:

```
function DialogElement() {
    this._template = "<div>Simple dialog!</div>";
}
```

May be there is a plugin suitable for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned [gulp-html2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html2js) and [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject), but they work not as expected.

So i make your salf [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-views) and and use it as:

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
    gulp
        .src('Controllers/*.js')
        .pipe(inject('Views/*.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

and chenge controller:

```
this._template = "{{load path='Views/Dialog.html'}}"
```